# How can the temperature of the processor, in less than 1 second, jump from 44*C to 54*C?

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-temperature

Im monitoring my processor temperatures on a 5930K and for a few of the cores, I see the temperatures jumping from about 44-46*C to 53-56*C in a instant, and then a few seconds later, a instant jump down.

I don't think a processor can heat up or cool down that fast, so what happening?

Comment: "I don't think […], so what's happening?" – False premise is happening.

Comment: A simple example as to why your intuition is likely wrong - just imagine an older style incandescent light bulb. We know when turned on its on its red/white hot - yet when you turn it off the light goes off instantly.  No reason the same types of fast transition can't happen on a CPU - especially when there is a whole fan & heatsink arrangement to dissipate heat quickly - and when a typical CPU uses - broadly speaking - between a quarter of and the same amount of energy of that light.

Comment: In fact, the i7-5930K you mention has a 140 watt tdp, so can consume more power then most incandescent light bulbs.

Comment: the space involved with a core temperature is so small, that yes it can experience dramatic fluctuations in very short periods of time. Die temp is a little slower to rise and fall than core temp, especially if there is no/insufficient cooling. Cores dissipate heat into the die, which hopefully dissipates it to the heat-sink/cooling system very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A processor like yours with a TDP of 140W can definitely heat up that fast. What's happening? Your processor isn't always using the same amount of power, so when the power usage jumps from 10W to more than 100W, you can expect a bump in core temperatures - pretty soon.

Couple of things to mention:

- 46°C is pretty cool for a processor like that. This could indicate that the processor is under really small loads, so there's absolutely nothing weird about the temps jumping up for about 10°C when the load momentarily increases
- CPU fan won't respond to a bump in temperature in milliseconds. Even if it did, it would take the cooler a couple of seconds after increasing fan speeds to actually cool down the CPU. So the temperature bumps like these are inevitable